# Possible to add Chrome option and capabilities together?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Possible to add Chrome option and capabilities together?

1. In need to combine the following listed below together, is it even possible?

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Base_Page.getConstant(Constant.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY));
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   string[] switches = {"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"};
   options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   options.addArguments("no-sandbox");

   LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
   logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
   options.(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);

   DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);

   DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
   logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
   caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
   caps.setCapability("chrome.switches", switches);
   //webdriver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
   webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   ```

Comment: could you explain little bit more..

Comment: @murali selenium thanks for the reply, in the above example i need to combine both the Capabilities and the options to one webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options). as you can see the webdriver instance is only assigned the option setup at the moment and not the Capabilities, is this even possible to combine the two? thanks for your help

Comment: Hey bit confused..sorry.. already created WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps); with combining caps and options right? this is the way we will do..right?

Comment: @murali selenium thanks again for your help, for example the following wouldn't be possible? webdriver = new ChromeDriver(caps, options);

Answer (score 2):

Searched the same question. 
The answer is: just add all your Capabilities into the "options" object and launch browser using options:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
webdriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest version of chrome driver fixed my issue:
ChromeDriver 2.28

Answer (score -1):

if you observe ChromeDriver constructor in below link

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html

It will accept capabilities or options, means any one. I hope it clears you.